# Using DATE part of datetime column in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, date, where

I'm building a POS system, where I collect the date & time that the event took place. I would like to pull some reports by only using the `DATE` part of the datetime column in my SQL queries.

My current query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_item_trans
WHERE  (date_time BETWEEN @start AND @end)
ORDER BY date_time DESC, code
```

However, if I put in two dates e.g. 14th and 15th September it only pulls data from 14. If I want to include 15th September transactions, the end date would have to be 16th September.

How can I solve this problem? It would be better also if I only used the `DATE` part of the `datetime` column.

the `@start` and `@end` variables use the `date` data type, e.g. '2017-09-16'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common):</sub>*

Try an *inclusive* start date and *exclusive* end date:

```
date_time >= @start AND date_time < DATEADD(day, 1, @end)
```

See also [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) by Aaron Bertrand.

---

Sargability wouldn't be a problem if the query is written to use `CAST(date_time AS DATE)`, since SQL Server will include a helper covering seek predicate. See [Understanding SARGability (to make your queries run faster)](http://www.sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event7/Understanding_SARGability_to_make_your_queries_run_faster) by Rob Farley (recorded at SQLBits VII in 2010) which demoed this. Note however that the conversion might still affect the accuracy of cardinality estimates.